# Little image in embed titles, Discord.js

Tags: javascript, embed, discord, discord.js, avatar

I've been trying to display little images in my embeds titles. But I can't make it work, the whole URL is displayed.
Code I tried to use:

```
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(message.author.displayAvatar)
        //I tried displayAvatarURL too
        .setDescription('Test');
        channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That icon is from [`embed.setAuthor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setAuthor).

```
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("My Title")
    .setAuthor("My Name", message.author.avatarURL)
    .setDescription("My Description");
    channel.send(embed);
```

And also to get the URL from the user avatar, on the current Discord.js version is `message.author.avatarURL` and not `displayAvatar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a little little image you need `defaultAvatarUR`

```
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.defaultAvatarUR)
        .setDescription('Test');
        channel.send(embed);
```

it's will be like this
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFz6s.png)